# Consider the surface $S$ given by the given equation $x^2 + xy+3y^2-z = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

(a) Find a parametric equation of the line passing through $(1,1,5)$ and perpendicular to $S$.

(b) Find an equation of the tangent plane to $S$ at $(1,1,5)$.

(c) Calculate the rate of change of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+xy+3y^2-z$ at $(1,1,5)$ in the direction of the vector $v=\langle 1,2,3\rangle$.

Part (a):

Given, $x^2 + xy+3y^2-z = 0$, I need to find the parametric equations of the surface.

Step 1 find parametric equations for surface $S$:
\begin{aligned}x^2 + xy +3y^2-z = 0  \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}z+(x^2 + xy +3y^2-z) = 0+z  \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}x^2 + xy +3y^2 = z  \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}x= \sin(t), y =\frac{1}{3}\cos(t)  \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}z = (\sin(t))^2 + (\sin(t))\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cos(t)\right) +3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cos(t)\right)^2  \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}z= \sin(t)^2 + \cos(t)^2 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cos(t)\sin(t) \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}z= 1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cos(t)\sin(t) \end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}x = \sin(t), y = \frac{1}{3}\cos(t),z= 1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cos(t)\sin(t) \end{aligned}
Step 2 Take derivatives of each of the parametric equations to obtain the  line that is tangent to the Surface:
\begin{aligned}\frac{dx}{dt}=\cos(t),\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\sin(t), \frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\cos(t)^2-\sin(t)^2}{\sqrt{3}} \end{aligned}
This would be the final answer for a: \begin{aligned} r(t) = \langle 1,1,5\rangle + \left\langle\cos(t),
\sqrt{3}\sin(t),\frac{\cos(t)^2-\sin(t)^2}{\sqrt{3}}\right\rangle \end{aligned}

Part (b):
\begin{aligned}F(x,y,z)= x^2 + xy+3y^2-z = 0\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}F_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0)+F_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0)+F_z(z-z_0)=0\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}F_x = 2x + y, F_y=x+ 6y, 
 F_z=-1,x_0=1,y_0=1,z_0=5\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}(3)(x-1) + (7)(y-1) +(-1)(z-5) = 0\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}3x-3 + 7y-7-z+5=0\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}5+(3x+7y-z-5)=0+5\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}3x+7y-z=5\end{aligned}
Part c:
\begin{aligned}\nabla{F(x,y,z)}=f_xi + f_yj+f_zk\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}\nabla{F(x,y,z)}=(2x+y)i+(x+6y)j+-1k\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}\nabla{F(1,1,5)}=3i+7j-k\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}D_u(1,1,5)=\nabla{F(1,1,5)} \cdot v\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}D_u(1,1,5)=(1)(3)+(7)(2)+(-1)(3)\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}D_u(1,1,5)=11\end{aligned}

Please give me any feed back on my solutions if they wrong please thank you.

Comment: It is OK. Simply we don't need the parametric form of the surface to find that line (the parametric form the wording asks is for the line): again, the gradient you calculated suffices. $r(t)=(1+3t,1+7t,5-t)$